# How to get output from a function called inside apply_sync in python2?

Tags: python-2.7

Using `ipyparallel` and python2 I am starting an `ipcontroller` and a single `ipengine` (both with --debug). In that engine I run code like follows:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp

def foo():
    import sys
    print("This is test 42")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return 42

rc = ipp.Client()
rc[:].apply_sync(foo)
```

I get the expected output `[42]` but nowhere I see the print output

```
This is test 42
```

Where is that output? How to get that output?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output, but this is [NOT properly documented](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asyncresult.html#metadata). It is stored in some metadata dict returned with the results.

Here is what you have to do:

```
results = rc[:].apply_sync(foo)
for metadata in result.metadata:
    print(metadata['stdout'])
```